# Headphones test fine but give static during actual use

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I'm using a pair of simple headphones connected to the audio jack of my Hp 2000 laptop running ubuntu 13.10. I've been having trouble with my headphones ever since I got them. Today, they just gave me a lot of static all day to the point of being unusable. After reading a few webpages on this and trying to clean out the headphone jack with some isopropol alchol, they still gave me static. I tried testing them in sound settings. I heard front left and front right clearly and crisply and was stunned. What could have caused this? Is it some sort of interference from my microphone. That would be strange considering I have my mic on unamplified 100% - OFF.

Answer (score 0):

As the sound test worked without problems you could try to use a different music player. If you only tried one format (e.g. only .mp3) you could try to play something different, e.g. an .ogg file (e.g. the login sound: /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Trying Different headphones can remove that. Your pair could be broken or it is the sound player. If its the sound player then try some different sounds or music players.